# use ifelse to create new column in r

Tags: r, if-statement

My code is:

```
data$E<-ifelse(data$D==data$B, "b", ifelse(data$D==data$C, "c", "unknowwn"))
```

result:

```
  A   B   C   D   E
1 16  16  NA  16  b
2 20  NA  20  20  NA
3 24  NA  NA  24  NA
```

But what I want is:

```
  A   B   C   D   E
1 16  16  NA  16  b
2 20  NA  20  20  c
3 24  NA  NA  24  unknowwn
```

Dose anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide [example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) in order to make your issue reproducible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data$E <- ifelse(!is.na(data$B) & data$D == data$B, "b", 
            ifelse(!is.na(data$C) & data$D == data$C, "c", "unknowwn"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is a bit complicated as you need to consider if either of columns `B`, `C` or `D` contains `NA`. Hence, you can try consider using `dplyr::case_when` as:

**Edited:** Based on suggestion from `@A.Suliman` there is no need to have checking for `is.na` with `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate( E = case_when(
  D==B ~ "b",
  D==C ~ "c",
  TRUE ~ "Unknown"
))

#    A  B  C  D       E
# 1 16 16 NA 16       b
# 2 20 NA 20 20       c
# 3 24 NA NA 24 Unknown
```

**Data:**

```
data <- read.table(text= 
"A   B   C   D   
1 16  16  NA  16  
2 20  NA  20  20
3 24  NA  NA  24",
header = TRUE)
```

Comment: No need for testing NA with `case_when`, I think `dplyr` magic works. See data %>% mutate(E = case_when(D==B ~ 'b',D==C ~ 'C', TRUE ~ 'Unknown'))